# Can JSoup handle two-step auth form?

Tags: java, jsoup, xenforo, two-step-verification

I'm trying to log into a page that uses xenForo for their forums.  I can log in fine without the two-step verification, but if a user is using two-step verification, is it possible to complete the login?

Here's the necessary HTML

```
<form action="login/two-step" method="post" class="xenForm AutoValidator" data-redirect="yes">
    <input name="code" id="ctrl_totp_code" class="textCtrl" type="text">
    <label><input name="trust" value="1" type="checkbox"> Trust this device for 30 days</label>
    <dd><input name="save" value="Confirm" accesskey="s" class="button primary" type="submit"></dd>
    <input name="provider" value="totp" type="hidden">
    <input name="_xfConfirm" value="1" type="hidden">
    <input name="_xfToken" value="" type="hidden">
    <input name="remember" value="0" type="hidden">
    <input name="redirect" value="https://www.WEBSITENAME.net/" type="hidden">
</form>
```

Here's what I tried:

```
        Document twoStepDoc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.WEBSITENAME.net/login/two-step")

        .data("cookieexists", "false")
        .data("code", code) //code is a String of my 2-step code I'm testing
        .data("trust", "1")
        .data("_xfConfirm", "1")
        .data("_xfToken", "")
        .data("remember", "0")
        .cookies(loginForm.cookies())
        .post()
    ;
```

It's late at night / early in the morning and I'm just trying anything right now :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it to work by giving everything a value.

```
        Document twoStepDocA = Jsoup.connect("https://www.WEBSITE.net/login/two-step")

        .data("cookieexists", "false")
        .data("code", code)
        .data("trust", "1")
        .data("save", "Confirm")
        .data("provider", "totp")
        .data("_xfConfirm", "1")
        .data("_xfToken", "")
        .data("remember", "0")
        .data("redirect", "https://www.WEBSITE.net")
        .cookies(loginForm.cookies())
        .post()
    ;
```